# IOS UI Test case for toggle button inside text field

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I am using the XCTest framework which is the default testing framework for UI Testing in IOS. 
I am writing a test case to check whether the text inside the text field is visible or hidden by clicking the hide show toggle button.

[image: IOS Toggle button inside text field]

The problem is that the toggle button is inside the text field and I am unable to access the toggle button.
On recording, it considers the tap on toggle button as tap on text field and generates code as follows :

```
let secureTextField = element3.children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 1).children(matching: .secureTextField).element
        secureTextField.tap()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do 2 things:

1. Set the toggle as an accessibility element
2. Give the toggle an accessibility identifier

Both may not be necessary depending on your current setup.

```
// app code
let toggleButton: UIButton!
toggleButton.isAccessibilityElement = true
toggleButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "showHideToggle"
```

This should allow XCTest to see the toggle and give you an easy mechanism to find it in your test code:

```
// test code
let app = XCUIApplication()
let toggle = app.buttons["showHideToggle"]
toggle.tap()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Will try and let you know if it works.
But, is there any other way in which we can do it?